# Traversing the US and Canada: A Cryptic Journey

Tags: knowledge, geography, cryptic-clues

Each answer is a place, landmark or attraction in the United States or Canada. The answers traverse all Canadian **provinces**, Canadian **territories**, U.S. **states** and the **District of Columbia**. This is done by crossing land borders where possible, although in a couple of cases crossing the sea is necessary as there are no land connections.

Each clue is missing a **state/province name** from another clue. (Not the *answer* to that clue, just the name of the administrative division.)

Note that some long names have been shortened. For example, if the full place name is "Xyz Royal National Park", the answer will be just "Xyz" (often with "royal national park" or similar as the definition).

> 1. Islamic extremists leave chaotic {43} USA salad to historic settlement (1'4 3 7)
>    2. {34} capital's borders hold extravagant Hopis regarding museum (9)
>    3. Anne's farm actor Clark and family coloured like {15} bay (5 6)
>    4. Familiar Margaret's top {11} vehicle duos produce fishing village (5'1 4)
>    5. Rapids turning around cliff's bottom, Cool J in author {24}'s birth initials (9 5)
>    6. National park's academic beginners with {4} finalists (6)
>    7. Actor Phoenix and second striker George follow series filmed in {64} canyon (4 5 5)
>    8. Region's east becomes west for {52}'s starters next to monarchy (9 7)
>    9. Primate and heartless CEO in briefly backwater {23} peninsula (4 3)
>   10. AC/DC bassist is after top-three {7} wine to stroll passageway (7 5 4)
>   11. Former {42} governor Eleanor familiarly leads to public park (8 4)
>   12. Felines unwell in short {57} back mountains (9)
>   13. Short {10} strangely cued a retired Wachowski waterway (6 5)
>   14. Fur post finally keeps top cards in {5} top two by the fifth street in hold'em (5 5)
>   15. Biblical figure's top-three {35} water park (4'1 3)
>   16. "The Knife" in a capital conundrum next to {3}'s last resort area (8 6)
>   17. Short {49} between pillars by haphazard sauna den sand formations (7 5)
>   18. Resort town president with top billing outside {12} capital's borders (3-2-3)
>   19. TV's Gomer east of {17} neighbour resort town (8)
>   20. Strike east twice from excited {21} in half-hearted book by ocean namesake town's pathway (8 4 9)
>   21. In front of seashore, bathe vigorously with {53} outsiders returning to coastal city (7 5)
>   22. Ford follows half of {26} capital with event host to stronghold (4 7)
>   23. Obelisk is {60} memorial structure (10 8)
>   24. Plantation east of {8} with one string instrument (10)
>   25. Historic town's sharper leader goes right, actress Tina embraces {48} capital couple (7 5)
>   26. Bullets and finally brought rich cognac within the edges of {50} govern central cavern system (7 4)
>   27. Elegance with {22}'s ending mansion (9)
>   28. Aged {61} capital is historic district (3 5)
>   29. Cay of friends having {33} loner is barrier island (4 2 5)
>   30. Forest's peculiar echo in {63} lake follows discussion (13)
>   31. National park's island near {51} mysteriously loses poles, takes five before finishing classes (10)
>   32. Coasts by body of water west of {31} resort city (4 6)
>   33. Without question, Vicky with rest of {19}'s capital leads to siege site (9)
>   34. Fifteen minutes behind {2}'s language neighbourhood (6 7)
>   35. Greek exclamations about the western part of {37} capital city (6 7)
>   36. Mountain city's {9} capital gets incomplete ransom for body (7)
>   37. Skyscraper or peach-shaped {29} building losing fluid for actor Bruce (6 5)
>   38. Settlements from {32}'s end with strange anise around colon (5 8)
>   39. Dale leaves {44} suburb, with deceit makes natural landmark (6 5)
>   40. Old cattle town is {16}-made car (5)
>   41. Lake's broken head following broken heart of {38} (6 3)
>   42. Battle site's returning {39} city not high end, keeps head low (5)
>   43. In the case of {27}, a soup brewed bloating heads leading to native community (4 6)
>   44. Lucky charm to twist a {46} River meander (9 4)
>   45. Half-fleecy westward ravine following {55}'s first and second national park (5 6)
>   46. Hold speech alongside {20} road with no turn to mountain (5 4)
>   47. Geyser not adulterous after initiating {41}'s long distance (3 8)
>   48. {13} band with additional mountain (8)
>   49. {6} loses foot, access lobster cooked within cottage (7 5 5)
>   50. Meeting place for short {40} (5)
>   51. Even {45} or steep mountain (4)
>   52. Okinawa city and {14} twins inspire top national park (7)
>   53. Gold rush town or {62} capital has endless dawn for a start (6 4)
>   54. Mountain's odd diesis holds {1} initials (6)
>   55. Last twos of East Asian capital and {59} make national park (4)
>   56. Mountain town to bar a duo from {36} capital (5)
>   57. Flexible EU skis alongside the shores of {25} lake (8)
>   58. Battle site is small, born holding {28} capital finishers (6 7)
>   59. National preserve to half-heartedly create soft heroin in designer {56}'s heart by beginning moonlight (7 2 3 4)
>   60. Volcano street next to {58} capital making a short head (2. 6)
>   61. Body of water's confusingly rare talk inside {47} capital's borders (6 4)
>   62. Left insane next to {18} company's man-made barrier (6 3)
>   63. {30} capital scorcher held in dodgy wash riff waterfront area (9'1 5)
>   64. Mountain top monitors a nuke blown up within {54}'s borders (5 3)

Comment: What do "1'4 3 7" and "9'1 5" mean?

Comment: Apostrophes, I'm fairly sure.

Comment: @jafe may I suggest changing the square brackets into curly ones as the square ones would be interpreted as hyperlinks in our answers? thanks!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
1. Islamic extremists leave chaotic [43] USA salad to historic settlement (1'4 3 7)
```

> L'ANSE AUX MEADOWS in NEWFOUNDLAND AND LABRADOR; 43 is NEW MEXICO

```
2. [34] capital's borders hold extravagant Hopis regarding museum (9)
```

> BIOSPHERE in QUEBEC; 34's capital is BATON ROUGE

```
3. Anne's farm actor Clark and family coloured like [15] bay (5 6)
```

> GREEN GABLES in PRINCE EDWARD ISLAND; 15 is WISCONSIN but I don't fully understand the wordplay

```
4. Familiar Margaret's top [11] vehicle duos produce fishing village (5'1 4)
```

> PEGGY'S COVE in NOVA SCOTIA; 11 is CONNECTICUT

```
5. Rapids turning around cliff's bottom, Cool J in author [24]'s birth initials (9 5)
```

> REVERSING FALLS in NEW BRUNSWICK; *Virginia* Woolf was born Adeline Stephen

```
6. National park's academic beginners with [4] finalists (6)
```

> ACADIA in MAINE; 4 is NOVA SCOTIA

```
7. Actor Phoenix and second striker George follow series filmed in [64] canyon (4 5 5)
```

> LOST RIVER GORGE in NEW HAMPSHIRE; 64 is HAWAII

```
8. Region's east becomes west for [52]'s starters next to monarchy (9 7)
```

> NORTHEAST KINGDOM in VERMONT; 52 is NORTHWEST TERRITORIES

```
9. Primate and heartless CEO in briefly backwater [23] peninsula (4 3)
```

> CAPE COD in MASSACHUSETTS; 23 is DC and apparently "backwater" means "backwards" now

```
10. AC/DC bassist is after top-three [7] wine to stroll passageway (7 5 4)
```

> NEWPORT CLIFF WALK in RHODE ISLAND; 7 is NEW HAMPSHIRE

```
11. Former [42] governor Eleanor familiarly leads to public park (8 4)
```

> BUSHNELL PARK in CONNECTICUT; 42 is Texas (not sure the "PARK" in the answer is actually clued here)

```
12. Felines unwell in short [57] back mountains (9)
```

> CATSKILLS in NEW YORK; 57 is SASKATCHEWAN

```
13. Short [10] strangely cued a retired Wachowski waterway (6 5)
```

> RIDEAU CANAL in ONTARIO; 10 is RHODE ISLAND

```
14. Fur post finally keeps top cards in [5] top two by the fifth street in hold'em (5 5)
```

> SNAKE RIVER in MINNESOTA; 5 is NE(w brunswick).

```
15. Biblical figure's top-three [35] water park (4'1 3)
```

> NOAH'S ARK in WISCONSIN; 35 is ARKANSAS

```
16. "The Knife" in a capital conundrum next to [3]'s last resort area (8 6)
```

> MACKINAC ISLAND in MICHIGAN; 3's last is ISLAND

```
17. Short [49] between pillars by haphazard sauna den sand formations (7 5)
```

> INDIANA DUNES in INDIANA; 49 is NORTH DAKOTA

```
18. Resort town president with top billing outside [12] capital's borders (3-2-3)
```

> PUT-IN-BAY in OHIO; 12 is NY, capital ALBANY

```
19. TV's Gomer east of [17] neighbour resort town (8)
```

> OHIOPYLE in PENNSYLVANIA; 17 is Indiana, its neighbour Ohio

```
20. Strike east twice from excited [21] in half-hearted book by ocean namesake town's pathway (8 4 9)
```

> ATLANTIC CITY BOARDWALK in NEW JERSEY (21 is DELAWARE)

```
21. In front of seashore, bathe vigorously with [53] outsiders returning to coastal city (7 5)
```

> BETHANY BEACH in DELAWARE; 53 is YukoN

```
22. Ford follows half of [26] capital with event host to stronghold (4 7)
```

> FORT MCHENRY in MARYLAND (26 is KY, capital Frankfort)

```
23. Obelisk is [60] memorial structure (10 8)
```

> WASHINGTON MONUMENT in DC; 60 is WASHINGTON

```
24. Plantation east of [8] with one string instrument (10)
```

> MONTICELLO in VIRGINIA; 8 is VERMONT

```
25. Historic town's sharper leader goes right, actress Tina embraces [48] capital couple (7 5)
```

> HARPERS FERRY in WEST VIRGINIA; "48 capital couple" is RR (Pierre, SD)

```
26. Bullets and finally brought rich cognac within the edges of [50] govern central cavern system (7 4)
```

> MAMMOTH CAVE in KENTUCKY; 50 is ManitobA

```
27. Elegance with [22]'s ending mansion (9)
```

> GRACELAND in TENNESSEE (22 is Maryland)

```
28. Aged [61] capital is historic district (3 5)
```

> OLD SALEM in NORTH CAROLINA; 61 is OREGON whose capital is SALEM

```
29. Cay of friends having [33] loner is barrier island (4 2 5)
```

> ISLE OF PALMS in SOuTH CAROLINA; 33 is MISSISSIPPI and I assume "loner" here means "single first letter of".

```
30. Forest's peculiar echo in [63] lake follows discussion (13)
```

> CHATTAHOOCHIE in GEORGIA; 63 is California (the lake is TAHOE)

```
31. National park's island near [51] mysteriously loses poles, takes five before finishing classes (10)
```

> EVERGLADES in FLORIDA; 51 is NUNAVUT, the island is GREENLAND

```
32. Coasts by body of water west of [31] resort city (4 6)
```

> GULF SHORES in ALABAMA; 31 is Florida, west of which is the GULF of Mexico

```
33. Without question, Vicky with rest of [19]'s capital leads to siege site (9)
```

> VICKSBURG in MISSISSIPPI; 19 is PENNSYLVANIA whose capital is (Harri)SBURG

```
34. Fifteen minutes behind [2]'s language neighbourhood (6 7)
```

> FRENCH QUARTER in LOUISIANA; 2 is QUEBEC

```
35. Greek exclamations about the western part of [37] capital city (6 7)
```

> EUREKA SPRINGS in ARKANSAS; 37 is ILLINOIS, capital SPRINGFIELD

```
36. Mountain city's [9] capital gets incomplete ransom for body (7)
```

> BRANSON in MISSOURI; 9 is Massachusetts, capital BOSTON

```
37. Skyscraper or peach-shaped [29] building losing fluid for actor Bruce (6 5)
```

> WILLIS TOWER in ILLINOIS; the Gaffney Peachoid is a *water tower*

```
38. Settlements from [32]'s end with strange anise around colon (5 8)
```

> AMANA COLONIES in IOWA (alabAMA + COLON in NAIES)

```
39. Dale leaves [44] suburb, with deceit makes natural landmark (6 5)
```

> SCOTTS BLUFF in NEBRASKA; 44 is Arizona; Scottsdale is a suburb of Phoenix

```
40. Old cattle town is [16]-made car (5)
```

> DODGE in KANSAS; 16 is MICHIGAN

```
41. Lake's broken head following broken heart of [38] (6 3)
```

> BROKEN BOW in OKLAHOMA; 38 is iOWa

```
42. Battle site's returning [39] city not high end, keeps head low (5)
```

> ALAMO in TEXAS; 39 is NEBRASKA, city is OMAHA

```
43. In the case of [27], a soup brewed bloating heads leading to native community (4 6)
```

> TAOS PUEBLO in NEW MEXICO (27 is Tennessee so TE)

```
44. Lucky charm to twist a [46] River meander (9 4)
```

> HORSESHOE BEND in ARIZONA; 46 is COLORADO

```
45. Half-fleecy westward ravine following [55]'s first and second national park (5 6)
```

> BRYCE CANYON in UTAH; 55 is BRITISH COLUMBIA

```
46. Hold speech alongside [20] road with no turn to mountain (5 4)
```

> PIKES PEAK in COLORADO; 20 is NEW JERSEY and the road is its TURNPIKE

```
47. Geyser not adulterous after initiating [41]'s long distance (3 8)
```

> OLD FAITHFUL in WYOMING; 41 is _O_KLAHOMA

```
48. [13] band with additional mountain (8)
```

> RUSHMORE in SOUTH DAKOTA; 13 is ONTARIO

```
49. [6] loses foot, access lobster cooked within cottage (7 5 5)
```

> MALTESE CROSS in NORTH DAKOTA; 6 is MAIN(e)

```
50. Meeting place for short [40] (5)
```

> (The) FORKS in MANITOBA; 40 is KS

```
51. Even [45] or steep mountain (4)
```

> THOR in NUNAVUT; 45 is UTAH

```
52. Okinawa city and [14] twins inspire top national park (7)
```

> NAHANNI in NORTHWEST TERRITORIES; 14 is miNNesota

```
53. Gold rush town or [62] capital has endless dawn for a start (6 4)
```

> DAWSON CITY in YUKON; 62 is NEVADA, capital CARSON CITY

```
54. Mountain's odd diesis holds [1] initials (6)
```

> DENALI in ALASKA; 1 is NEWFOUNDLAND AND LABRADOR

```
55. Last twos of East Asian capital and [59] make national park (4)
```

> YOHO in BRITISH COLUMBIA (tokYO + idaHO)

```
56. Mountain town to bar a duo from [36] capital (5)
```

> BANFF in ALBERTA; 36 is MISSOURI, capital is Jefferson City

```
57. Flexible EU skis alongside the shores of [25] lake (8)
```

> WASKESIU in SASKATCHEWAN; 25 must be WEST VIRGINIA

```
58. Battle site is small, born holding [28] capital finishers (6 7)
```

> LITTLE BIGHORN in MONTANA; so 28 must be NORTH CAROLINA with capital RALEIGH

```
59. National preserve to half-heartedly create soft heroin in designer [56]'s heart by beginning moonlight (7 2 3 4)
```

> CRATERS OF THE MOON in IDAHO; the designer is *Alberta* Ferretti with RE in the middle

```
60. Volcano street next to [58] capital making a short head (2. 6)
```

> ST. HELENS in WASHINGTON; 58 is MONTANA

```
61. Body of water's confusingly rare talk inside [47] capital's borders (6 4)
```

> CRATER LAKE in OREGON (47 is WYOMING, capital CHEYENNE)

```
62. Left insane next to [18] company's man-made barrier (6 3)
```

> HOOVER DAM in NEVADA; 18 is OHIO where the Hoover company was founded

```
63. [30] capital scorcher held in dodgy wash riff waterfront area (9'1 5)
```

> FISHERMAN'S WHARF in CALIFORNIA; 30 is GEORGIA (Sherman)

```
64. Mountain top monitors a nuke blown up within [54]'s borders (5 3)
```

> MAUNA KEA in HAWAII; 54 is AlaskA

Comment: Fixed the typo in #20. The "heart" in #59 is correct but it refers to a person's name.

Comment: Removed the typo-correction in #20 :-).

Comment: OK, done (and fixed up the wordplay in #59).

Comment: All correct! Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

Partial

34. Fifteen minutes behind {2}'s language neighbourhood (6 7)

> [FRENCH QUARTER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Quarter) ({2}'s language = French, Fifteen minutes = quarter, def = neighbourhood)

55. Last twos of East Asian capital and {59} make national park (4)

> [ISLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isle_Royale_National_Park) (Illino**is** + Ma**le** (capital of Maldives))

Answer (score 0):

Partial:

> 23. **Washington, DC**. Obelisk is Washington memorial structure = **WASHINGTON MONUMENT**. 
>  28. **North Carolina**. Aged (OLD) Oregon capital (SALEM) is historic district = **OLD SALEM**. 
>  41. Lake's broken head following broken heart of [38] (6 3) 
>  47. **Wyoming**. Geyser not adulterous (RELIABLE) after initiating [Ohio/Ontario/Oklahoma]'s long distance (OLD) = **OLD RELIABLE**. 
>  58. **Montana**. Battle site is small (LITTLE), born holding North Carolina capital finishers (end of Raleigh = IGH in B__ORN) = **LITTLE BIGHORN**. 
>  60. **Washington**. Volcano street (ST) next to Montana capital making a short head (Helena - A + S) = **ST. HELENS** 
>  61. **Oregon**. Body of water's confusingly rare talk (RATER LAK) inside Wyoming capital's borders (Cheyenne borders = C____E) = **CRATER LAKE**.