# Traversing Latin America & Caribbean: A Cryptic Journey

Tags: knowledge, geography, cryptic-clues

<sub>Earlier parts in the series: [Africa](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80282), [US & Canada](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80479), [Oceania](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84748).</sub>

---

Each answer is a **place**, **landmark** or **attraction** in Latin America or the Caribbean, one per country. The answers traverse all countries by crossing land or (approximate) maritime borders. Each clue is missing a **country name** from another clue (not the *answer* to that clue, just the name of the country).

Notes:

- Some long names have been shortened. For example, if the full place name is "Xyz Royal National Park", the answer will be just "Xyz" (often with "royal national park" or similar as the definition).
- While many of the answers are obscure, all of them are notable enough to have a separate article on the English Wikipedia.
- In addition to the sovereign states of the region, I have included four other countries holding territory in the Caribbean: **France**, **Netherlands**, the **United Kingdom** and the **United States**.
- The **Bahamas**, **Guyana** and **Suriname**, while not a part of either Latin America or the Caribbean, have been included as a bonus because you are such good customers.

> 1. Circle behind top vikings, sail out around western part of {3}'s port (10)
>    2. Essential to visitors: a {25}n national park (6)
>    3. French city near the borders of {31}'s capital city (7)
>    4. A con man exits {32}'s capital, having first climbed mountain (9)
>    5. {35} replacing mediocre beach fronts with top-notch historic city (7)
>    6. {29}'s leaders call head of state, having at first used force behind one border landmark (6 5)
>    7. Coastal town's wine mixed with uranium near {10} capital (5 9)
>    8. Actress Holmes loses heart, tells about {5}an beginners loudly by a waterfall (8 5)
>    9. All fangs lost around {30}'s first and second waterfall (5 5)
>   10. No {21} Orchestra's starters returned to town (5)
>   11. Behind {24}'s borders, cast iron to overwhelm wetland (6 5)
>   12. Before uninitiated information has finally lost, {28}'s capital loses rights to fossil site (7 9)
>   13. {11} island is associated with oddly crazy small islands (6 4)
>   14. {20} president is against brief evacuations, returning to underground hole (8'1 4)
>   15. Nails in {17}'s mountains (6)
>   16. Last of four leading {2}ns goes west by unnaturally leaking body of water (7 4)
>   17. Isles needing no introductions – {13}'s honorific precedes multiple extremely small islands (3 7)
>   18. Elton replaces Michael Knight's car in largest part of {19}'s seat of government (2. 4'1)
>   19. Fortress's edge next to one hill receiving {15}'s honorific (9 4)
>   20. The Italian in front of {6}ian city governor's residence (2 9)
>   21. Spin inner troll's head inside {36}'s spinning mountain (4 6)
>   22. {12}n lost following southeastern river (6-4)
>   23. Leading men in black turn tail to ski beyond {7}'s central district (6)
>   24. A company for short friend in half of {18} city (7)
>   25. Blackjack opponent behind {26} county museum (5 5)
>   26. Famous seafront: Several thousand {1} leaders struck by big head ache unexpectedly (5 4 5)
>   27. Complex Canon copy containing contracted {37} ravine (6 6)
>   28. {9} capital excluded as cold central archaeological site (7)
>   29. In {22}, kaleidoscope leads to ruin (5)
>   30. Laurel loses shirt, earns poorly around top {16}n archaeological site (3 6)
>   31. Within Mexico, {34}nian archaeological site (5)
>   32. Found in {23}, a Yankee's volcano (6)
>   33. {4} leaders on left lane to volcano (6)
>   34. Weirdly vocal First Nation in front of central {14} primary railroad halfway up a mountain (6 4)
>   35. Guitarist Paul follows turbulent {33}n river (4 9)
>   36. Company to almost pass central {27}'s mountain (8)
>   37. Third traveller lost in {8}'s wild forest region (6)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Circle behind top vikings, sail out around western part of {3:PARAGUAY}'s port (10)
>  VALPARAISO in CHILE
>     2. Essential to visitors: a {25:JAMAICA}n national park (6)
>  SAJAMA in BOLIVIA
>     3. French city near the borders of {31:HONDURAS}'s capital city (7)
>  VILLETA in PARAGUAY
>     4. A con man exits {32:NICARAGUA}'s capital, having first climbed mountain (9)
>  ACONCAGUA in ARGENTINA
>     5. {35:COLOMBIA} replacing mediocre beach fronts with top-notch historic city (7)
>  COLONIA [del Sacramento] in URUGUAY
>     6. {29:GUATEMALA}'s leaders call head of state, having at first used force behind one border landmark (6 5)
>  IGUACU FALLS in BRAZIL
>     7. Coastal town's wine mixed with uranium near {10:NETHERLANDS} capital (5 9)
>  NIEUW AMSTERDAM in SURINAME
>     8. Actress Holmes loses heart, tells about {5:URUGUAY}an beginners loudly by a waterfall (8 5)
>  KAIETEUR FALLS in GUYANA
>     9. All fangs lost around {30:EL SALVADOR}'s first and second waterfall (5 5)
>  ANGEL FALLS in VENEZUELA
>     10. No {21:DOMINICAN REPUBLIC} Orchestra's starters returned to town (5)
>  NOORD in THE NETHERLANDS
>     11. Behind {24:CUBA}'s borders, cast iron to overwhelm wetland (6 5)
>  CARONI SWAMP in TRINIDAD AND TOBAGO
>     12. Before uninitiated information has finally lost, {28:BELIZE}'s capital loses rights to fossil site (7 9) 
>  BELMONT FORMATION in GRENADA
>     13. {11:TRINIDAD AND TOBAGO} island is associated with oddly crazy small islands (6 4)
>  TOBAGO CAYS in SAINT VINCENT AND THE GRENADINES
>     14. {20} president is against brief evacuations, returning to underground hole (8'1 4)
>  HARRISON'S CAVE in BARBADOS
>     15. Nails in {17}'s mountains (6)
>  PITONS in ST LUCIA
>     16. Last of four leading {2:BOLIVIA}ns goes west by unnaturally leaking body of water (7 4)
>  BOILING LAKE in DOMINICA
>     17. Isles needing no introductions – {13:SAINT VINCENT AND THE GRENADINES}'s honorific precedes multiple extremely small islands (3 7)
>  LES SAINTES in Guadeloupe, a territory of FRANCE
>     18. Elton replaces Michael Knight's car in largest part of {19}'s seat of government (2. 4'1)
>  ST. JOHN'S in ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA
>     19. Fortress's edge next to one hill receiving {15:SAINT LUCIA}'s honorific (9 4)
>  BRIMSTONE HILL in SAINT KITTS AND NEVIS
>     20. The Italian in front of {6:BRAZIL}ian city governor's residence (2 9)
>  LA FORTALEZA in Puerto Rico, a territory of the UNITED STATES
>     21. Spin inner troll's head inside {36:ECUADOR}'s spinning mountain (4 6)
>  PICO DUARTE in DOMINICAN REPUBLIC
>     22. {12:GRENADA}n lost following southeastern river (6-4)
>  GRANDE-ANSE in HAITI
>     23. Leading men in black turn tail to ski beyond {7:SURINAME}'s central district (6)
>  BIMINI in BAHAMAS
>     24. A company for short friend in half of {18:ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA} city (7)
>  BARACOA in CUBA
>     25. Blackjack opponent behind {26:UNITED KINGDOM} county museum (5 5)
>  DEVON HOUSE in JAMAICA
>     26. Famous seafront: Several thousand {1:CHILE} leaders struck by big head ache unexpectedly (5 4 5)
>  SEVEN MILE BEACH in the Cayman Islands, a territory of the UNITED KINGDOM
>     27. Complex Canon copy containing contracted {37:PERU} ravine (6 6)
>  COPPER CANYON in MEXICO
>     28. {9} capital excluded as cold central archaeological site (7)
>  CARACOL in BELIZE
>     29. In {22}, kaleidoscope leads to ruin (5)
>  TIKAL in GUATEMALA
>     30. Laurel loses shirt, earns poorly around top {16:DOMINICA}n archaeological site (3 6)
>  SAN ANDRES in EL SALVADOR but I don't understand the first part
>     31. Within Mexico, {34:PANAMA}nian archaeological site (5)
>  COPAN in HONDURAS
>     32. Found in {23:BAHAMAS}, a Yankee's volcano (6)
>  MASAYA in NICARAGUA
>     33. {4:ARGENTINA} leaders on left lane to volcano (6)
>  ARENAL in COSTA RICA
>     34. Weirdly vocal First Nation in front of central {14:BARBADOS} primary railroad halfway up a mountain (6 4)
>  VOLCAN BARU in PANAMA
>     35. Guitarist Paul follows turbulent {33:COSTA RICA}n river (4 9)
>  CANO CRISTALES in COLOMBIA
>     36. Company to almost pass central {27:MEXICO}'s mountain (8)
>  COTOPAXI in ECUADOR
>     37. Third traveller lost in {8:GUYANA}'s wild forest region (6)
>  YUNGAS in PERU (thanks to El-Guest for finding this when I had failed to!)

Credit where due: I didn't manage to

> locate a forest region in Peru that was an anagram of GUYANS

but El-Guest found one.

Comment: Does traveller potentially clue for vowel in some weird way?

Comment: I don't see how it would -- but even if so, wouldn't that mean losing an A just as it does if "third traveller" means the third letter of `traveller`?

Comment: How does [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yungas) look, @GarethMcCaughan ?

Comment: (And yes - third letter of traveller is a better clueing.)

Comment: Looks excellent. Well found!

Comment: Opinions sought: should I redact the country names I've interpolated into the clues, since those aren't spoilered? Or spoiler the whole thing? Or leave it as it is? (What I have right now seems unlikely to be best. I confess I forget that the country names were visible...)

Comment: Thanks very much!! If you look at what I did for the Africa one (jafe has linked it above), I figured it was best to spoiler the whole thing, personally.