# Traversing Eurasia: A Cryptic Journey

Tags: knowledge, geography, cryptic-clues

<sub>Earlier parts in the series: [Africa](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80282), [US & Canada](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80479), [Oceania](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84748), [Latin America & Caribbean](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85176).</sub>

---

Each answer is a **place**, **landmark** or **attraction** in Eurasia, one per country. The answers traverse all countries by crossing land or maritime borders. (In some cases, it's necessary to pass through a previous country in order to get to the next one.) Each clue is missing a **country name** or **demonym** from another clue (not the *answer* to that clue, just the name of the country).

Notes:

- Some long names have been shortened. For example, if the full place name is "Xyz Royal National Park", the answer will be just "Xyz" (often with "royal national park" or similar as the definition).
- While many of the answers are obscure, all of them are notable enough to have a separate article on the English Wikipedia.
- The list of countries includes all Eurasian members of the United Nations plus **Kosovo**, **Palestine**, **Taiwan** and **Vatican City**.
- The country names mostly follow Wikipedia's naming conventions: Myanmar instead of Burma, East Timor instead of Timor-Leste, etc. However, Ireland is just Ireland here.

> 1. Sixth of the prophets leaves {$55$}n holy city that is former capital (5)
>   2. Active volcano in {$80$} (4)
>   3. A preface to {$68$}'s a small river (4)
>   4. {$24$}'s second city drops retired grub to public square (2. 5'1)
>   5. University town shows early signs of Greater {$64$} (4)
>   6. Scan around area beyond {$77$}'s easternmost and largest city (6)
>   7. Large waterfall flowing near hills around {$23$}'s capital (5 5)
>   8. Low-lying region for learning map unusually, following direction of {$43$} (5 6 5)
>   9. {$44$}k letter functions as series of constructions (5 5)
>   10. A drink knocked back east of {$9$}' first subnational capital (5)
>   11. By way of human's right, eastern {$22$} identifies canton's capital (7)
>   12. Setting for Van Gogh paintings of two decapitations on {$30$}'s most prominent bridge (5)
>   13. Mountain top tour in {$59$} ruined by twisted leg (4 4)
>   14. Directions lost in {$73$} ski resort village (3)
>   15. After finally travelling inside {$60$}, boy returns up river (9)
>   16. Hidden in fluff, a {$35$}n summer destination (4)
>   17. Girl in front of {$20$}'s eastern seaport (6)
>   18. {$75$} finishing challenging skyscraper (5)
>   19. {$32$}'s westernmost lake stirred to reveal volcano (5)
>   20. {$79$} losing constituents as Winter Olympic host (4)
>   21. Leg exchanged for head in {$29$} theme park (8)
>   22. Some abysmal {$34$}n border city (5)
>   23. Contemporary art museum found in {$31$}'s maps (6)
>   24. Initially, Ottomans mismanaged {$91$}n remote major city (4)
>   25. {$51$}'s leader joining a festival showing waterfall (6)
>   26. Eastern {$52$} has grand capital (4)
>   27. Flying ark at {$19$}'s premier island castle (6)
>   28. {$70$}'s leader leaves chest to 19th-century fortress (5)
>   29. Village of eastern {$39$} getting \$100 for fifth place (8)
>   30. Second city from {$84$}'s island dismissing premiers in open election (4)
>   31. Small {$50$}ian capital is making a massive castle (4)
>   32. "Muscular" city's short specifications missing ending in {$88$} (4)
>   33. Float in the air above central {$37$} behind large mountain (7)
>   34. Second city overlooking easternmost part of {$27$}'s sea (5)
>   35. {$41$}'s core trio taking top of ruined, scary castle (4)
>   36. Former capital's central unit is against {$47$}'s conclusion (3)
>   37. Trekking couple embraces close to {$56$} tourist island (3)
>   38. {$11$}'s leader going to bed, showing "injured" town (4)
>   39. No introduction for {$87$}'s renovated bridge (5 4)
>   40. Port of {$28$} fails to include central figures of Dell and Bush (3)
>   41. Head to vacation near one {$2$}ian seaside village (4)
>   42. {$8$}, among others, does not have any park in the mountains (6)
>   43. Piece of gum at {$65$} canyon (5)
>   44. Vacation island of western {$42$} (3)
>   45. Buried in {$74$}n Orthodox monastery (4)
>   46. {$93$}man overturned concealing city of 1001 churches (3)
>   47. Coin lost next to terminals in {$86$}'s capital (7)
>   48. Coastal city initially taking {$58$}i refugees before end of warfare (4)
>   49. Secretly assist a {$6$}er returning to port (5)
>   50. Biblical city of Jerusalem's leaders are against wealthy {$3$}'s far right (7)
>   51. Wild ape getting around central {$5$}n archaeological site (5)
>   52. Long-beaked bird circles {$21$}'s central mountain (6)
>   53. Ruin headgear near the middle of {$49$} (5)
>   54. Closure of {$92$} event locales for shopping mall (7)
>   55. Detective inspector leaves {$72$} following man to neighbourhood (4)
>   56. A free look in front of {$4$}'s third military fort (2 4)
>   57. Near {$67$}'s capital, amazing relief of extremely elegant 400-year-old plant (4 2 4)
>   58. Governorate's capital is inside {$76$}'s borders, originally (3)
>   59. South {$15$}ish city famous for its shipyards (3)
>   60. Large area around the heart of {$89$} oasis (4)
>   61. Radioactive material found in ruined {$1$} castle (6)
>   62. {$61$} corruption behind grand temple (5)
>   63. Dictator's birthplace from the smallest state after central {$94$} (4)
>   64. Secretly rob a {$54$}i home town of chess legend (4)
>   65. Ancient city of {$69$} missing many new innovations, at first (9)
>   66. River brings a {$26$}n back in secret (5)
>   67. Couple goes around third sign in {$62$}n mountain range (5)
>   68. In front of ash tree's top, {$18$} county's capital (8)
>   69. Westernmost region of {$40$}'s peninsula (6)
>   70. Goddess is followed by {$46$}'s top city (5)
>   71. In {$12$}, the cab comes first to archaeological site (6)
>   72. State nothing in the case of {$63$} (3)
>   73. Lowland region held by returning {$82$} retailer (5)
>   74. National park in {$83$}n retreat (4)
>   75. Heads of {$57$}'s administration aboard to show tropical atoll (3)
>   76. Fortress revealed by a {$66$}i opening inside of glass container (5)
>   77. Beach resort for {$13$} finalists in front of very small marketplace (3'1 5)
>   78. Protected lake cabin: {$48$}ese keeping secret (4)
>   79. {$90$}ese leaders follow field of leading rocket scientists, displaying archaeological area (5 2 4)
>   80. Nomadic Central Asian loses foot before the opening of {$25$}'s former capital (3)
>   81. Tropical archipelago is analogous with north, not close to {$78$} (7)
>   82. Provincial capital of {$33$}, no United Nations leaders having tea (6)
>   83. Coastal city of note drawing in {$17$}'s top duo (4)
>   84. {$36$}'s half-hearted coastal town (5)
>   85. Before, {$38$}'s outsiders shipped nothing to tourist island (7)
>   86. Regularly, {$10$} man wanting to go around a vacation spot (4)
>   87. {$7$} finally starts to initiate luxuriating its capital (4)
>   88. Tall volcano within {$85$} (3)
>   89. University inside {$16$}'s borders close to one central city (4)
>   90. {$45$}'s officials in possession of large active volcano (3)
>   91. River ends in rich area near {$71$}'s eastern border (3)
>   92. Held in {$14$}'s only seaport (5)
>   93. Herder's heading out of {$81$}'s western mountain (3)
>   94. Wetland retreating next to {$53$}'s primary desert (4)

Comment: Is there a letter missing from clue 12?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Fixed #12. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Sixth of the prophets leaves {55}n holy city that is former capital (5)
>
>  MDINA in MALTA
>
>  2. Active volcano in {80:VIETNAM} (4)
>
>  ETNA in ITALY
>
>  3. A preface to {68:UZBEKISTAN}'s a small river (5)
>
>  AUSA in SAN MARINO
>
>  4. {24}'s second city drops retired grub to public square (2. 5'1)
>
>  ST PETER'S in VATICAN CITY
>
>  5. University town shows early signs of Greater {64:AZERBAIJAN} (4)
>
>  GRAZ in AUSTRIA
>
>  6. Scan around area beyond {77:BANGLADESH}'s easternmost and largest city (6)
>
>  SCHAAN in LIECHTENSTEIN
>
>  7. Large waterfall flowing near hills around {23:FINLAND}'s capital (5 5)
>
>  RHINE FALLS in SWITZERLAND
>
>  8. Low-lying region for learning map unusually, following direction of {43:NORTH MACEDONIA} (5 6 5)
>
>  NORTH GERMAN PLAIN in GERMANY
>
>  9. {44:GREECE}k letter functions as series of constructions (5 5)
>
>  DELTA WORKS in the NETHERLANDS
>
>  10. A drink knocked back east of {9:NETHERLANDS}' first subnational capital (5)
>
>  NAMUR in BELGIUM
>
>  11. By way of human's right, eastern {22:SWEDEN} identifies canton's capital (7)
>
>  VIANDEN in LUXEMBOURG
>
>  12. Setting for Van Gogh paintings of two decapitations on {30}'s most prominent bridge (5)
>
>  ARLES in FRANCE
>
>  13. Mountain top tour in {59:OMAN} ruined by twisted leg (4 4)
>
>  MONTAGEL in MONACO
>
>  14. Directions lost in {73:NEPAL} ski resort village (3)
>
>  PAL in ANDORRA
>
>  15. After finally travelling inside {60:UAE}, boy returns up river (9)
>
>  GUADALUPE in SPAIN
>
>  16. Hidden in fluff, a {35:ROMANIA}n summer destination (4)
>
>  FARO in PORTUGAL
>
>  17. Girl in front of {20:NORWAY}'s eastern seaport (6)
>
>  GALWAY in IRELAND
>
>  18. {75:MALDIVES} finishing challenging skyscraper (5)
>
>  The SHARD in the UNITED KINGDOM
>
>  19. {32:HuNGARY}'s westernmost lake stirred to reveal volcano (5)
>
>  HEKLA in ICELAND
>
>  20. {79} losing constituents as Winter Olympic host (4)
>
>  OSLO in NORWAY
>
>  21. Leg exchanged for head in {29:POLAND} theme park (8)
>
>  LEGOLAND in DENMARK
>
>  22. Some abysmal {34:MOLDOVAN}n border city (5)
>
>  MALMO in SWEDEN
>
>  23. Contemporary art museum found in {31:SLOVAKIA}'s maps (6)
>
>  KIASMA in FINLAND
>
>  24. Initially, Ottomans mismanaged {91:SOUTH KOREA}n remote major city (4)
>
>  OMSK in RUSSIA
>
>  25. {51:JORDAN}'s leader joining a festival showing waterfall (6)
>
>  JAGALA in ESTONIA
>
>  26. Eastern {52:SYRIA} has grand capital (4)
>
>  RIGA in LATVIA
>
>  27. Flying ark at {19:ICELAND}'s premier island castle (6)
>
>  TRAKAI in LITHUANIA
>
>  28. {70:AFGHANISTAN}'s leader leaves chest to 19th-century fortress (5)
>
>  BREST in BELARUS
>
>  29. Vilage of eastern {39:BOSNIA AND HERZEGOVINA} getting $100 for fifth place (8)
>
>  ZEGOCINA in POLAND
>
>  30. Second city from {84}'s island dismissing premiers in open election (4)
>
>  BRNO in CZECHIA / CZECH REPUBLIC
>
>  31. Small {50:PALESTINE}ian capital is making a massive castle (4)
>
>  SPIS in SLOVAKIA
>
>  32. "Muscular" city's short specifications missing ending in {88} (4)
>
>  PECS in HUNGARY
>
>  33. Float in the air above central {37:CROATIA} behind large mountain (7)
>
>  HOVERLA in UKRAINE
>
>  34. Second city overlooking easternmost part of {27:LITHUANIA}'s sea (5)
>
>  BALTI in MOLDOVA
>
>  35. {41:ALBANIA}'s core trio taking top of ruined, scary castle (4)
>
>  BRAN in ROMANIA
>
>  36. Former capital's central unit is against {47:CYPRUS}'s conclusion (3)
>
>  NIS in SERBIA
>
>  37. Trekking couple embraces close to {56:QATAR} tourist island (3)
>
>  KRK in CROATIA
>
>  38. {11:LUXEMBOURG}'s leader going to bed, showing "injured" town (4)
>
>  BLED in SLOVENIA. (Thanks to El-Guest for suggesting this. I hadn't considered Bled because the clue said "city" and I was looking at a list of places with a population of at least 10k; with about 8700 people, I wouldn't consider Bled a *city*. Clue has now changed to say "town".)
>
>  39. No introduction for {87:EAST TIMOR}'s renovated bridge (5 4)
>
>  STARI MOST in BOSNIA AND HERZEGOVINA
>
>  40. Port of {28:BELARUS} fails to include central figures of Dell and Bush (3)
>
>  BAR in MONTENEGRO
>
>  41. Head to vacation near one {2:ITALY}ian seaside village (4)
>
>  VUNO in ALBANIA
>
>  42. {8:GERMANY}, among others, does not have any park in the mountains (6)
>
>  GERMIA in KOSOVO
>
>  43. Piece of gum at {65:KAZAKHSTAN} canyon (5)
>
>  MATKA in NORTH MACEDONIA
>
>  44. Vacation island of western {42:KOSOVO} (3)
>
>  KOS in GREECE
>
>  45. Buried in {74:SRI LANKA}n Orthodox monastery (4)
>
>  RILA in BULGARIA
>
>  46. {93:CHINA}man overturned concealing city of 1001 churches (3)
>
>  ANI in TURKEY
>
>  47. Coin lost next to terminals in {86:INDONESIA}'s capital (7)
>
>  NICOSIA in CYPRUS
>
>  48. Coastal city initially taking {58:YEMEN}i refugees before end of warfare (4)
>
>  TYRE in LEBANON
>
>  49. Secretly assist a {6:LIECHTENSTEIN}er returning to port (5)
>
>  EILAT in ISRAEL
>
>  50. Biblical city of Jerusalem's leaders are against wealthy {3:SAN MARINO}'s far right (7)
>
>  JERICHO in PALESTINE
>
>  51. Wild ape getting around central {5:AUSTRIA}n archaeological site (5)
>
>  PETRA in JORDAN
>
>  52. Long-beaked bird circles {21:DENMARK}'s central mountain (6)
>
>  HERMON in SYRIA
>
>  53. Ruin headgear near the middle of {49:ISRAEL} (5)
>
>  HATRA in IRAQ
>
>  54. Closure of {92:NORTH KOREA} event locales for shopping mall (7)
>
>  AVENUES in KUWAIT
>
>  55. Detective inspector leaves {72:INDIA} following man to neighbourhood (4)
>
>  MINA in SAUDI ARABIA
>
>  56. A free look in front of {4:VATICAN CITY}'s third military fort (2 4)
>
>  AL KOOT in QATAR
>
>  57. Near {67:TAJIKISTAN}'s capital, amazing relief of extremely elegant 400-year-old plant (4 2 4)
>
>  TREE OF LIFE in BAHRAIN
>
>  58. Governorate's capital is inside {76:BHUTAN}'s borders, originally (3)
>
>  IBB in YEMEN
>
>  59. South {15:SPAIN}ish city famous for its shipyards (3)
>
>  SUR in OMAN
>
>  60. Large area around the heart of {89:TAIWAN} oasis (4)
>
>  LIWA in the UAE
>
>  61. Radioactive material found in ruined {1:MALTA} castle (6)
>
>  ALAMUT in IRAN
>
>  62. {61:IRAN} corruption behind grand temple (5)
>
>  GARNI in ARMENIA
>
>  63. Dictator's birthplace from the smallest state after central {94:MONGOLIA} (4)
>
>  GORI in GEORGIA
>
>  64. Secretly rob a {54:KUWAIT}i home town of chess legend (4)
>
>  BAKU in AZERBAIJAN
>
>  65. Ancient city of {69:TURKMENISTAN} missing many new innovations, at first (9)
>
>  TURKESTAN in KAZAKHSTAN (usually called TURKISTAN now)
>
>  66. River brings a {26:LATVIA}n back in secret (5)
>
>  TALAS in KYRGYZSTAN
>
>  67. Couple goes around third sign in {62:ARMENIA}n mountain range (5)
>
>  PAMIR in TAJIKISTAN
>
>  68. In front of ash tree's top, {18:UNITED KINGDOM} county's capital (8)
>
>  TASHKENT in UZBEKISTAN
>
>  69. Westernmost region of {40:MONTENEGRO}'s peninsula (6)
>
>  BALKAN in TURKMENISTAN (thanks to El-Guest for figuring this out even when the clue said "Easternmost" at the start instead of "Westernmost"!)
>
>  70. Goddess is followed by {46:TURKEY}'s top city (5)
>
>  HERAT in AFGHANISTAN
>
>  71. In {12:FRANCE}, the cab comes first to archaeological site (6)
>
>  TAXILA in PAKISTAN
>
>  72. State nothing in the case of {63:GEORGIA} (3)
>
>  GOA in INDIA
>
>  73. Lowland region held by returning {82:CAMBODIA} retailer (5)
>
>  TERAI in NEPAL
>
>  74. National park in {83:MALAYSIA}n retreat (4)
>
>  YALA in SRI LANKA
>
>  75. Heads of {57:BAHRAIN}'s administration aboard to show tropical atoll (3)
>
>  BAA in the MALDIVES
>
>  76. Fortress revealed by a {66:KYRGYZSTAN}i opening inside of glass container (5)
>
>  JAKAR in BHUTAN
>
>  77. Beach resort for {13} finalists in front of very small marketplace (3'1 5)
>
>  COX'S BAZAR in BANGLADESH
>
>  78. Protected lake cabin: {48:LEBANON}ese keeping secret (4)
>
>  INLE in MYANMAR
>
>  79. {90:JAPAN}ese leaders follow field of leading rocket scientists, displaying archaeological area (5 2 4)
>
>  PLAIN OF JARS in LAOS
>
>  80. Nomadic Central Asian loses foot before the opening of {25:ESTONIA}'s former capital (3)
>
>  HUE in VIETNAM
>
>  81. Tropical archipelago is analogous with north, not close to {78:MYANMAR} (7)
>
>  SIMILAN in THAILAND
>
>  82. Provincial capital of {33:UKRAINE}, no United Nations leaders having tea (6)
>
>  KRATIE in CAMBODIA
>
>  83. Coastal city of note drawing in {17:IRELAND}'s top duo (4)
>
>  MIRI in MALAYSIA
>
>  84. {36:SERBIA}'s half-hearted coastal town (5)
>
>  SERIA in BRUNEI
>
>  85. Before, {38:SLOVENIA}'s outsiders shipped nothing to tourist island (7)
>
>  SENTOSA in SINGAPORE
>
>  86. Regularly, {10:BELGIUM} man wanting to go around a vacation spot (4)
>
>  BALI in INDONESIA
>
>  87. {7:SWITZERLAND} finally starts to initiate luxuriating its capital (4)
>
>  DILI in EAST TIMOR
>
>  88. Tall volcano within {85:SINGAPORE} (3)
>
>  APO in the PHILIPPINES
>
>  89. University inside {16:PORTUGAL}'s borders close to one central city (4)
>
>  PULI in TAIWAN
>
>  90. {45:BULGARIA}'s officials in possession of large active volcano (3)
>
>  ASO in JAPAN
>
>  91. River ends in rich area near {71}'s eastern border (3)
>
>  HAN in SOUTH KOREA
>
>  92. Held in {14}'s only seaport (5)
>
>  RASON in NORTH KOREA
>
>  93. Herder's heading out of {81:THAILAND}'s western mountain (3)
>
>  TAI in CHINA
>
>  94. Wetland retreating next to {53}'s primary desert (4)
>
>  GOBI in MONGOLIA

I see that there are other partial answers; quite possibly their authors solved some of these before I did. I haven't looked.

Credit where due: El-Guest figured out the answers to three clues (3,38,69) that were wrong while they were still wrong, which I totally failed to do in all three cases.

Comment: Gareth — I think the clue for 3 was changed to 4 letters instead of 5....

Comment: Oooh! I didn't notice that. Thanks.

Comment: No problem! See my answer for 38, as well — think there’s one more four letter city, perhaps....

Comment: You're clearly right -- though its population is about the same as that of the _village_ I live in, so "city" seems a bit extreme.

Comment: Didn't realize #38 was that small... I've changed it to "town" now. Sorry about that.

Comment: I’ve spent way too much time thinking about 69, so if you want a laugh check out my answer. Don’t think it’s right but it’s kinda close. Anyway, great job!!

Comment: Wow, I hope that one's wrong :-).

Comment: Nope, it's correct (and I'm a donkey...)

Comment: Great puzzle again @jafe — I love your cryptic geography puzzles! That was still a neat clue for 69, even with the incorrect direction I didn’t know there was a word shared between that peninsula and that westernmost region!

Comment: Oh man, #65 could have been so much better if I had used the current name... For some reason, Wikivoyage lists it with the "e" spelling. All correct so far, so 92/94 done!

Comment: Whoops, didn't even notice I hadn't done 24. Will look at that again. What's the other missing one? [24 done now. Still failing to see what else isn't there.]

Comment: #22 is the remaining one.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan good find on #24 — I think I got #22!

Comment: Well done! Good find.

Comment: It was missing because I hadn't noticed it wasn't done yet, not because it was difficult :-).

Answer (score 5):

1) Sixth of the prophets leaves {55}n holy city that is former capital (5)

> Country: Malta. Answer: MDINA (MEDINA - E)

2)  Active volcano in {80} (4)

> Country: Italy. Answer: ETNA (viETNAm) [Thanks, @Omega Krypton]

3) A preface to {68}'s a small river (4)

> Country: San Marino. Answer: AUSA (__'S A...?)

4) {24}'s second city drops retired grub to public square (2. 5'1)

> Country: Vatican City. Answer: ST. PETER'S (wordplay....?)

5) University town shows early signs of Greater {64} (4)

> Country: Austria. Answer: GRAZ (GReater AZerbaijan)

22) Some abysmal {34}n border city (5)

> Country: Sweden. Answer: MALMO (abysMAL MOldovan)

38) {11}'s leader going to bed, showing "injured" city (4)

> Country: Slovenia. Answer: BLED (L from Luxembourg in BED, BLED def. injured)

49) Secretly assist a {6}er returning to port (5)

> Country: Israel. Answer: ??

50) Biblical city of Jerusalem's leaders are against wealthy {3}'s far right (7)

> Country: Palestine. Answer: JERICHO (Jerusalem's leaders JE + wealthy RICH + San Marino's right O)

51) Wild ape getting around central {5}n archaeological site (5)

> Country: Jordan. Answer: PETRA (anag of ape: PEA, PE +ausTRian +A) [Thanks, @Omega Krypton]

53) Ruin headgear near the middle of {49} (5)

> Country: Iraq. Answer: HATRA (headgear HAT + middle of isRAel)

55) Detective inspector leaves {72} following man to neighbourhood (4)

> Country: Saudi Arabia. Answer: MINA (M + [INDIA - DI])

56) A free look in front of {4}'s third military fort (2 4)

> Country: Answer:  (vaTican city)

61) Radioactive material found in ruined {1} castle (6)

> Country: Iran. Answer: ALAMUT (radioactive material uranium U in anag. MALTA)

62) {61} corruption behind grand temple (5)

> Country: Armenia. Answer: GRANI (anag. IRAN behind G)

63) Dictator's birthplace from the smallest state after central {94} (4)

> Country: Georgia. Answer: GORI (central monGOlia + smallest state Rhode Island)

64) Secretly rob a {54}i home town of chess legend (4)

> Country: Azerbaijan.

67) Couple goes around third sign in {62}n mountain range (5)

> Country: . Answer:  (incl. Armenia)

69) Easternmost region of {40}'s peninsula (6)

> Country: Turkmenistan. Answer: BALKAN (okay, bear with me here..... Montenegro is in the Balkan Peninsula; Balkan is the *Westernmost* region of Turkmenistan, and this is the closest I can get to a reasonable answer.....@jafe am I totally wrong??)

72) State nothing in the case of {63} (3)

> Country: India. Answer: GOA (nothing O in the case [outside] of GeorgiA). (I’m personally so proud of this one because my mom’s family is Goan!!!)

80) Nomadic Central Asian loses foot before the opening of {25}'s former capital (3)

> Country: Vietnam

94) Wetland retreating next to {53}'s primary desert (4)

> Country: Mongolia. Answer: GOBI (BOG, reversed + Iraq's first letter)

Comment: Ahh sorry, the enumeration of #3 was wrong. It's supposed to be 4, not 5. Counting is hard!

Comment: Ahhh yes that makes more sense, thanks @jafe!

Comment: #69 is right. Fixing the clue now...

Answer (score 4):

2)  Active volcano in {80} (4)

> ETNA (viETNAm)

51) Wild ape getting around central {5}n archaeological site (5)

> PETRA (anag of ape: PEA, PE +ausTRian +A)

80) Nomadic Central Asian loses foot before the opening of {25}'s former capital (3)

> AVA (nomAdic + V_? + A_?)